# Seeking a generic way to read reports from HID devices in C#

Tags: c#, windows, usb, hid

First off, a little context to what I am trying to do.
I am the author of [IOWrapper](https://github.com/evilC/IOWrapper), a library that allows you to read input (Keyboard, Mouse, Joystick etc) and send output (Keyboard, mouse, virtual joystick etc) using arbitrary APIs (DirectInput, XInput, RawInput etc) all via a standardized interface.

New forms of IO can be supported by adding an MEF plugin to IOWrapper (We call them "Providers") and one Provider typically wraps one API, for example the DirectInput provider can enumerate and read DI devices, the vJoy provider can control virtual vJoy sticks, etc.
All IOWrapper cares about are devices which have inputs (or outputs) which look like they are a Button, Axis (Joystick style Absolute, or Mouse style relative) or POVs ("Hat Switches").
The GUI front-end for our application ([UCR](https://github.com/Snoothy/UCR)) can then be totally agnostic about APIs and such - it is only concerned with mapping buttons to buttons etc.

I am investigating the possibility of writing a provider for USB HID (At first input only), as there are some devices which seem to expose all of their capabilities via HID, but the higher-up windows APIs either do not see the devices or see them in a limited capacity.
For example, a "DS4" (Playstation 4) controller has a touchpad on it, but when viewing it via DirectInput (or say in joy.cpl), the regular axes and buttons are available, but not the touchpad.
Another example would be 3D mice, which often have a combination of absolute and relative axes - these seem to be fully exposed at the HID level, but for example you won't see them exposed as DirectInput devices in games.

Now there are USB HID implementations for some of these devices (eg [DS4Windows](https://github.com/Jays2Kings/DS4Windows) for DS4 pads), but I would like to try and make something as generic as possible, without having to write a complete implementation for each device.

I have done some research, and on [this page](http://eleccelerator.com/tutorial-about-usb-hid-report-descriptors/), I get the impression that a HID device exposes all the information that you need to be able to work out how many buttons/axes/povs it has, and how to interpret it's reports.
I guess you would lose information such as button names (eg on a DS4 controller, you would just get "Button 1", not "Cross"), but I guess we could allow optional XML files to give names to the various buttons - hell even if it required minor coding (Deriving from a class, overriding some stuff), that would not be too bad.

So with this goal in mind, I set about trying to write some POC code.
I first tried [hid-sharp](https://github.com/jcoenraadts/hid-sharp), but the examples seemed broken - `devices[selectedDeviceIndex].serialNumber` was always 0 or null, and I could not proceed.

I then tried the NuGet package [HIDSharp](https://www.zer7.com/software/hidsharp) - the 1.5 version I was able to get reports from one of my devices, but I see no way to get at the descriptors to work out how to interpret those values.

In the test app for 2.0 alpha, It crashes on the following code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns the raw report descriptor of the USB device.
/// Currently this is only supported on Linux.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>The report descriptor.</returns>
public virtual byte[] GetReportDescriptor()
{
    throw new NotSupportedException(); // Windows without libusb can't... Linux can.
}
```

The Report Descriptor seems to be what I am after, so I am not sure how to proceed at this point. If there is another dependency to do what I want, then fine, no problem, but even with it satisfied, I lack the code.

So, I am making this post in the hopes that someone can help guide me through this minefield, or tell me not to bother trying to cross it.

There seems to be quite a lot of code out there, but a lot of it seems to not be maintained or hosted on a git repo. The HidSharp 2.0 alpha looks like it was maybe headed in the right direction, and is recent (Dec 2017), so I am hoping that may materialize soon. I will probably ping some of the devs involved to see if I can get their input.

Comment: I have released HidSharp 2.0. It should meet your needs quite well. Let me know if you run into any bugs with it. :)

Comment: Thanks man, gonna have a tinker now